# Convert mp3 to ogg via php

Tags: php, mp3, ogg

I have a website where users can upload music and get it converted to mp3, but I need mp3 and ogg file support to play the music in html5. So, is there any php script that can convert mp3 to ogg?

Comment: There is unlikely to be a PHP script. Can you use command-line tools like ffmpeg?

Comment: it's to many files to download and upload agen..

Comment: I think @Pekka is suggesting you run these tools server-side from within PHP

Comment: Ok, i'm not so good at things like that. I feel a little noob here. How do you do that?

Answer (score 4):

Use ffmpeg.
You can execute commands directly from your php script.

Comment: It is also available as a PHP extension, but in my experience, it is far easier just to call the command line version.