# Convert * (mp3, m4p, and the likes) to OGG via Command Line for HTML5 compatibility

Tags: php, windows, command-line, mp3, ogg

What options do I have for converting MP3's to OGG on the fly using PHP? I assume the only way to do this is via the command line with an execute statement. Is this true? If so, what converters (and associated commands) would I be best off using?

I have tried:

oggenc2.exe but was told by the program that the MP3 I passed was not a valid filetype

ffmpeg.exe but was unable to figure out how to go from mp3 to ogg (found how to go from ogg to mp3 though)

[Convert mp3 to ogg via php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105134/convert-mp3-to-ogg-via-php)

Comment: cli questions typically belong on superuser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't look very far...

**exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i infile.mp3 -acodec libvorbis outfile.ogg");**

Comment: Upvoted, although I doubt an OS that can run "oggenc2.exe" has a `/usr/bin/` directory ;)

Comment: Yes, it is a windows system. I did not mention that in the actual post but I did put a tag. I apologize if I was ambiguous.

Comment: Just change the path from `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` to `C:/path/to/ffmpeg.exe` is only an example but perhaps i should of noted that ;p

Comment: I will give it a shot! Thanks Lawrence. Where it says -acodec, do I put that string literal or am I supposed to switch it to something custom?

Answer (score 1):

It is now recommended (see note below) to use avconv to convert audio and video files instead of ffmpeg.

```
avconv -i in.mp3 -ar 16000 out.ogg
```

Where 16000 is the sample rate. You can inspect the sample rate of the source file with:

```
file in.mp3
```

Note: I got this warning on my Ubuntu box using ffmpeg: THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED. This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.

Comment: Very good to know. Thank you very much. I've already selected a best answer, but please keep the good work up!

Comment: You may need to add additional codecs for this to work. I had to add:
 sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-*
to my Ubuntu system.